# How to increment a variable caught with sed?

Tags: shell, replace, sed, increment

I have a sed script that would catch a phrase `objID="x"`, where x can be any positive integer.

I would like to increment it a by a constant value, let's say 100 in whole file. How can I do that?

```
sed 's/objID="\(\d\)"/objID="\1"/g
```

What should I change in that ?

Comment: gnu sed could do it, but awk, perl will do it easier. Is sed a MUST?

Comment: @Kent `sed` is not a must. That's just a tool I know the most (amongst others like e.g. `awk` )

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo 'objID="1"' |
    perl -pe 's/(objID=")(\d+)(")/sprintf "%s%s%s", $1, $2+1, $3/ge'
objID="2"
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ echo 'objID="1"' | awk -F'"' '/objID=/{print $1 $2+1 $3}'
objID="2"
```

Comment: The perl example works but fine but awk will not work for lines with more `"`s.

Answer (score 1):

as I commented, awk, perl would do the job easier, however if sed is a must requirement, take a look this example:

(**Gnu Sed** required)

```
kent$  echo 'objID="7"'|sed -r 's/(objID=")([0-9]+)(")/echo \1$((100+\2))\3/ge'
objID=107
```